# Converting GeoJSON into a flat JSON with jq

Tags: json, jq, geojson

Let's say I have the following GeoJSON file:

```json
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "name": "geojson",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": 1,
        "value1": 4.7557783e-06,
        "value2": 0
      },
      "geometry": null
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": 1,
        "value1": 1.4931199e-05,
        "value2": 5
      },
      "geometry": null
    }
  ]
}
```

I know that with the line `cat file.geojson | jq '.features[].properties'` I can get the following result:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "value1": 4.7557783e-06,
  "value2": 0 
}   
{     
  "id": 1,
  "value1": 1.4931199e-05,
  "value2": 5
}
```

However, I'd like to have this result inside an array like the following:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value1": 4.7557783e-06,
    "value2": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value1": 1.4931199e-05,
    "value2": 5
  }
]
```

How can I add the brackets `[]` and the proper commas `,` with `jq` to form this last flat JSON file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could wrap your whole filter into brackets

```sh
jq '[.features[].properties]' file.geojson
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/IgCPhvDUms)

Or take advantage of the fact that `.features` is already an array and just `map` its contents.

```sh
jq '.features | map(.properties)' file.geojson
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/tD_uYMg7vx)

Both output

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value1": 4.7557783e-06,
    "value2": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value1": 1.4931199e-05,
    "value2": 5
  }
]
```